# Xcode warning "profiling: invalid magic number"

Tags: ios, xcode, ocunit, xcode4.6

I just installed Xcode 4.6. When I run my OCUnit tests now, I get multiple lines with "profiling: invalid magic number" in the output window after all tests have finished. I'm pretty sure that Xcode 4.5.2 didn't give me that output.

Does anybody know what this line means?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After some googling I found this LLVM source file [GCDAProfiling.c](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/lib/profile/GCDAProfiling.c)

From what I can see there, the error is printed during the code coverage generation when the profiler is attempting to merge two files but one of them has a different version (= magic number).

I did a full Clean (it also removes all `gcda` files) and the problem went away.

Comment: I find that cleaning the build folder clears the errors for the first run through the tests, but the errors return for subsequent runs of the unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up having to delete the appropriate DerivedData folder for my application -

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/#application-name#

But that ended up clearing everything up.