# xcodebuild gives “profiling: invalid magic number”, doesn't generate coverage files

Tags: xcode, profiling, xcodebuild, gcov

Let's get this out of the way first: **This question is not a duplicate** of [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14585477/30461). I'll explain why below.

I'm running the command `xcodebuild test -scheme 'ISO8601ForCocoa' SYMROOT=../build`, and here's the output:

> ```
> Executed 16 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.047 (0.051) seconds
> profiling: invalid magic number (0x656d6954)
> profiling: invalid magic number (0x00000000)
> ** TEST SUCCEEDED **
> ```

The person who asked that earlier question got the same error message, but they fixed it by cleaning their build folder.

In my case, cleaning will not help, because *I don't have a build folder yet*. I still get this error message even on a completely fresh build. In fact, the .gcda and .gcno files are not even created, so there is nothing to clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xcodebuild puts build products in `$SYMROOT`, but stores *profile* products in `$OBJROOT`.

If you want to completely confine a build, including all intermediate and ultimate products, to a single directory, you need to set three build settings:

- `SYMROOT`: Build Products Path (ultimate products, such as apps and test bundles)
- `OBJROOT`: Intermediate Build Files Path (intermediate products, such as per-module object files—generated by the compiler, read by the linker—and .gcno/.gcda files)
- `SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR`: Precompiled Headers Cache Path (guess)